# Changing default output of a function

Tags: functions, print

When I run `(+ 1 1)` using `eval-print-last-sexp` in a buffer, this function inserts a newline and outputs 2. I'd rather its output were just ' 2' (space and 2).

How can I change this?

Comment: The question is not clear. **How** are you evaluating that sexp? Evaluation itself does not print anything - it simply returns 2. Your question is likely about the function (command) that is actually printing the value, but you give no recipe. The question will likely be deleted unless it is clarified.

Comment: @Drew fair enough, done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for `evaluate-print-last-sexp`, minus the docstring.  (Note: I found this with `C-h f evaluate-print-last-sexp`, and following the link to the source code.)

```el
(defun eval-print-last-sexp (&optional eval-last-sexp-arg-internal)
  "(DOCSTRING HERE)"
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((standard-output (current-buffer)))
    (terpri)
    (eval-last-sexp (or eval-last-sexp-arg-internal t))
    (terpri)))
```

It calls the function `terpri`, whose docstring reads:

> `terpri` is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> `(terpri &optional PRINTCHARFUN)`
>
> Output a newline to stream PRINTCHARFUN.
>   If PRINTCHARFUN is omitted or `nil`, the value of `standard-output` is used.

So `terpri` hardcodes your extra newlines.  Your simplest
solution is probably to rewrite this function and strip out the calls to `terpri`:

```el
(defun my-eval-print-last-sexp (&optional eval-last-sexp-arg-internal)
  "I hate newlines."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((standard-output (current-buffer)))
    (eval-last-sexp (or eval-last-sexp-arg-internal t))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might simply use `eval-last-sexp` with a prefix instead of `eval-print-last-sexp`. For me this is already bound to `C-x C-e`, so I just need to type `C-U C-x C-e`.